# Well-founded recursion using (Acc lt (x-y))

Tags: recursion, coq, well-formed

In [A Tutorial on[Co-]Inductive Types in Coq](http://www.labri.fr/perso/casteran/RecTutorial.pdf) on p. 47, a recursive function is defined, where each recursive step uses a well-formedness proposition to show that the recursion terminates.

A function that is called with `x` makes a recursive call with `x-y` where `y<>0`, so it should terminate.

I am not able to enter it into Coq without getting an error.  Coq is complaining that the recursion argument is *not* smaller in the call, while the tutorial claims that it is so.

What am I missing?

I rewrote the code slightly to make it shorter, but I also tried the verbatim definitions in the paper.

First we show that `x-y` is accessible from x.

```coq
Require Import Omega.

Definition minus_decrease:
  forall x y, Acc lt x -> x<>0 -> y<>0 -> Acc lt (x-y).
  intros x y H Hx Hy.
  case H; intro Ha; apply Ha.
  omega.
Qed.
```

Next, when trying to define the function, like this

```coq
Definition div_aux :=
  fix div_aux (x y:nat) (H:Acc lt x) {struct H}: nat :=
  match eq_nat_dec x 0 with
    |left _ => 0
    |right _ =>
     match eq_nat_dec y 0 with
       |left _ => 0
       |right v => S (div_aux (x-y) y (minus_decrease x y H _ v))
     end
  end.
```

then Coq refuses, saying

> Recursive call to div_aux has principal argument equal to
>   "minus_decrease x y H ?156 v" instead of a subterm of "H".

Notice how `div_aux x ...` calls itself recursively with `div_aux (x-y) ...`, and `(minus_decrease ...)` returns a term of type `Acc lt (x-y)`

How do I use `Acc` to show that this function actually terminates?

Answer (score 3):

The error seems to be that I ended the definition with `Qed.` instead of `Defined.`  The following works.

```
Require Import Omega.

Definition minus_decrease: forall x y, Acc lt x -> x<>0 -> y<>0 -> Acc lt (x-y).
  intros x y H Hx Hy.
  case H; intro Ha; apply Ha.
  omega.
Defined.


Fixpoint div_aux (x y:nat) (H:Acc lt x) {struct H}: nat.
Proof.
  refine (if eq_nat_dec x 0
          then 0
          else if eq_nat_dec y 0
               then y
               else S (div_aux (x-y) y _)).
  apply (minus_decrease _ _ H _H _H0).
Qed.
```

Comment: Yes, Coq needs to be able to inspect the output of ``minus_decrease`` to assert it is actually structurally smaller than ``H``. By using ``Qed`` instead of ``Defined``, you block this inspection so Coq termination checker can't do its job.